# Editing the rich text field breaks the formatting

Tags: lightning, formatting

Within the screen flow we are using a custom "inputrichtextfsc" component where we are passing a classic e-mail template with formatting.

1. This is the e-mail template (just for an example): [image]
2. When you look on the screen flow on the lightning record page, formatting is the same as in the template: [image]
3. However, when you try to edit the e-mail body, the formatting is breaking and you can't do anything about it: [image]

Can anyone help with understanding why does this happen and how to avoid formatting changes so that the e-mail would look the same as in the template (and also to have an option to edit the e-mail body before sending it).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The e-mail template has specific formatting that actually is lost if you edit the e-mail content on the record page - this is the main issue.

What I want: so that the formatting that is set in the template remains, even if I edit the content of the e-mail.